# Remove special characters except alt codes using PHP

Tags: php, regex

I'm removing special characters to my string but when I am trying to run the code it removes the last number like from **hello113** into **hello11** and etc. Then I found out the those numbers are using in [alt codes](https://tools.oratory.com/altcodes.html) for special characters.

This is what I am trying to do

```
$var = "hello113 guys115 this is for test&ing101!";
preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z])+\w{2}/i', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', '', $var), $var_data);

echo strtolower(implode(" ", $var_data[0]));
```

And then the result is like this

```
hello11 guys11 this for test ing10
```

I am expecting this kind of result:

```
hello113 guys115 this is for testing101
```

Comment: What is expected output for `hello113 guys115 this is for test&ing101!`? Remove all punctuation? `preg_replace('~[\p{P}\p{S}]+~u', '', $var_data)` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/OsUrQq/1))?

Comment: Are you sure you don't just want [htmlspecialchars](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) ?

Comment: alt codes? the `{2}` is causing the issue :/

Comment: I  tried this but didn't worked. `preg_match_all('/([a-zA-Z])+\w/i', preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\']/', ' ', $var), $var_data);` I removed the `{2}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just remove all non whitespace and non-word characters.

```
$var = "hello113 guys115 this is for test&ing101!";
echo preg_replace('/[^\w\s]|_/', '', $var);
```

Result:

> hello113 guys115 this is for testing101

https://3v4l.org/jeebk

The `|_` is because `\w` allows for underscores.

You can add the `u` modifier after the closing delimiter if unicode word characters also are allowed.

```
preg_replace('/[^\w\s]|_/u', '', $var)
```

Comment: Note it will not work with Unicode strings. Then, you will have to use `preg_replace('~[\p{P}\p{S}]+~u', '', $var_data)`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Won't the `u` modify the `\w` to extend to unicode word chars?

Comment: @user3783243 It will.